# Android:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a big problem with android studio & none of the answers helped me . It happen when I want to get APK file . It's The error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/27.1.2/lint-gradle-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/27.1.2/lint-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-checks-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.1.2/lint-checks-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-api-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/27.1.2/lint-api-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find intellij-core-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/27.1.2/intellij-core-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.1.2/kotlin-compiler-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find uast-27.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/27.1.2/uast-27.1.2.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-4.1.0-alpha01-6193524.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.0-alpha01-6193524).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.1.0-alpha01-6193524/aapt2-proto-4.1.0-alpha01-6193524.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Please help me if you can . I realy need it . Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the error as well so that we can debug and find a potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that ! I just deleted these files :

```
project_folder/.gradle
project_folder/.idea
project_folder/.gradle
project_folder/build
project_folder/app/build
project_folder/app/release
C:\\users\Your_Name\.gradle\caches
```

Then open Android Studio & execute again .